# Android crash report doesn't send to developer console

Tags: android, crash-reports

I have been testing my application with my relatives through distribution via Google Play's alpha testing feature. Crashes have been showing under "Crashes & ANRS" for a while. However, there have been many crashes in the past few days but none have shown up on this page at all. I have spoken with them and they have assured me that there have been crashes and that they have been reporting them and sending them off to Google.

Does anyone know why the Crashes & ANRS page on the Google Play Developer Console doesn't pick up these crash reports anymore? I haven't contacted Google about this yet but I will do so now as well.

edit:

Okay so I just checked today and all of the crash reports have just shown up. I guess it can take up to a day or so for the reports to show up.

It was just a case of not being patient enough.

Comment: I just ran into this where I had a few users email me saying they experienced crashes and I didn't see any crash reports, so I'm assuming they'll show up in a day or so. Still, this is a really terrible way to report bugs, since you theoretically can't fix a bug for a couple days with this time frame, really annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I just checked today and all of the crash reports have just shown up. I guess it can take up to a day or so for the reports to show up.

It was just a case of not being patient enough.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend you use [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com). Then you will have actionable crash reports immediately, both in release and during development if you so wish.

You can also know with some confidence whether your app is actually stable or not, and prioritise what you need to fix.

Answer (score 2):

So, there are two points here:

1) It depends on the user's decision to 'Send Report' (or not) on any crash perceived during app usage. To check all of the stack traces generated by your application, you must implement third-party crash reporter or start testing Firebase Crash Reporting (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash).

2) In my experience using the Google Play console, a reported crash/ANR may take some hours to reach your dashboard.