# Alpha testing on Google Play crash statistics

Tags: android, google-play

I've been Alpha testing for a few weeks now with Google Play Developer Console, and I've had 3 or 4 crashes("Unfortunately this app has stopped working.").

**Why am I not seeing crashes on the Developer Console Crashes and ANRs page?** Is there some setting I'm missing?

Comment: have you reported this crashes?

Comment: @Jorgesys: No. I wanted to ask on SO before I report it, to see if there is any special setup in the Developer Console for Alpha Testing with Crash Statistics.

Answer (score 3):

There's no special configuration in `Google Developer Console`.
to see the statistics of `Crashes` and `ANRs`, it must be reported by the user, even if your app is in alpha/beta testing.

Comment: I cannot find the crash reports even if they are reported in the ANR and Crashes Tab. My app is in alpha testing. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you uploaded your .apk in Google developer console? your app must be downloaded from the play store in alpha testing.

Comment: Yep I did. I realized that it takes up to 24 hours for the crash and ANR to show up in the console. That might be the reason for it not showing up immediately. Here's a similar question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198375/android-crash-report-doesnt-send-to-developer-console)